How to view the weighting matrix used in geographically weighted regression
I am currently using geographically weighted regression with Fixed Gaussian kernel. I have the GWR result, but I would like to see the weighting matrix used for the model. Is there a way to view it?
Here's my code:
gwr.fit <- gwr(y ~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5, 
               data = df_spatial, 
               bandwidth = gwr_band, 
               se.fit = T, 
               hatmatrix = T, 
               gweight = gwr.Gauss)

I have tried gwr.fit$SDF but it only returns the result of the GWR model.

Hi ng_05, welcome to SO. It is important to provide a minimal, reproducible example when asking a question. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Also, there are at least two packages with functions called gwr() so please update your question with the name of the package you are using. Thanks
